# Copy strings with limited characters

Tags: c, string

Alright this is a homework question whereby I can't use the string.h library. This function is to copy not more than n characters (characters that
follow a null character are not copied) from the array pointed to by s2 to the array pointed to by s1.

```
int main()
{
    char sourceString[100];
    char targetString[100];
    int num;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    gets(sourceString);
    printf("Enter no. of characters: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("stringncpy(): %s", stringncpy(targetString, sourceString, num));
}

char *stringncpy(char * s1, char * s2, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s2[i] != '\0')
        {
            s1[i] = s2[i];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    s1[i] = '\0';
    return s1;
}
```

It runs fine except that it is printing some rubbish unrecognizable characters after n characters. Apprantly running the code with http://ideone.com/, I don't get those rubbish characters but on VS it does.

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that the result of `s1[i] == '\0'` isn't used, because it's a comparsison. Use assignment `=` here.

Comment: @MOehm Yes, sorry, typo.

Comment: Well, it's also the solution to your problem, no? Because the garbage characters come from not null-terimating the string.

Comment: by the way, `gets` is evil... and did this solve the question ?

Comment: Oh it did. Somehow when I re-complie earlier on I was facing the same error. I know about the gets() situation, using it here is to keep things simple.

Comment: So this can be closed/deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Because `gets` is used it is better to use

```
     if (s2[i] != '\0' && s2 [i] != '\n')
```

instead if

```
      if (s2[i] != '\0')
```

And if `n` define the max numer of character you should ensure that `n < 100`. When after `for` loop `i == n` writing `'\0'` to i-th position can cause a problem. Or maybe loop should be

```
     for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```